# How do I calculate the 95% confidence interval of a curve that depends on many parameters?

Tags: confidence-interval, curve-fitting

Assuming I have a curve fit that depends on 4 parameters. How would I compute the 95% confidence interval if I had many variations of this curve fit (many combinations of samples of these 4 parameters). I tried taking the 95% interval for each parameter separately, but this seems completely wrong as it gives borders that are outside of my actual fits. Here is an example of what I have. In black is the average fit and around it is all the different variations.

[image: curve fit with variations]

As you can see, depending on what X value, it is not always the same curve that is "on top" or "on the bottom". Thus, I'm not sure how to compute the 95% CI.

I basically have a list containing the 4 parameters for each fit.

Comment: Can you share how these lines were created? Perhaps by bootstrapping?

Comment: By "curve *fit* that depends on four parameters," I'm led to believe you mean to say that you have a univariate linear model that is a third-order polynomial, so $y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2 + \beta_3 x^3 + \epsilon$. But that is only one way to make a univariate curve fit with four parameters. Here is a nonlinear example: $y=\beta_0+ \beta_1 x^{\beta_2} \exp( -\beta_3 x) + \epsilon$. Please be more specific. It you mean the linear model, then the 95% confidence interval for prediction $\hat{y}_i(x_i)$ is a simple formula.

Comment: The generic answer is that a 95% *simultaneous confidence region* for the parameters designates the set of curves you want.  There are many ways to determine such a region, but they all require you to specify a probability model for the data and to stipulate how you are using that to estimate the parameters.  Could you provide some details?

Comment: one approach is to take individual 95% intervals not on the parameters, but on the actual value of the function at each point that you're plotting.

Comment: @whuber I don't know if this is what you mean, but my different fits all come from a uniform distribution. Thus they all have the same probability of occurring.

Comment: @JohnMadden Hmm this could work, but how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Uniform distribution of what?  What are the formulas for the curves and why is there any uncertainty in the fit?  @John That works.  It would be the *envelope* of the fitted values, but it would lose all information about the curves themselves.